# im having trouble with webhooks in discord,js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i am trying to make a discord bot that resends users deleted messages as a webhook and i am having trouble displaying the users avatar

```
bot.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {

    bot.channels.cache.get("717764123265466398")
    .createWebhook(messageDelete.author.username, messageDelete.author.avatarURL)
    .then(wb => wb.send(messageDelete.content))

            })
```

i have this piece of code that is meant to detect when a user deletes a message and it will create a webhook and send that message in a webhook back to the channel with the users name as the webhook name and the users avatar as the webhook avater however it sends the webhook with the name but the avatar does not show on the webhook

Answer (score 0):

Try `.avatarURL()` instead of just `.avatarURL`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Then try `messageDelete.author.displayAvatarURL()` instead